# I'm not able to insert an image in the top center on my project's cover

Tags: graphics, overleaf, abnt

So, I'm using a portuguese template, sorry about that, and here are the commands:

```
 % Informações de dados para CAPA e FOLHA DE ROSTO
% ---
\titulo{Modelo Canônico de\\ Trabalho Acadêmico com \abnTeX}
\autor{Equipe \abnTeX}
\local{Brasil}
\data{2014, v-1.9.2}
\orientador{Lauro César Araujo}
\coorientador{Equipe \abnTeX}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Imagens/FDUSP.jpg}
\end{figure}

\tipotrabalho{Tese (Doutorado)}
% O preambulo deve conter o tipo do trabalho, o objetivo, 
% o nome da instituição e a área de concentração 
\preambulo{Modelo canônico de trabalho monográfico acadêmico em conformidade com
as normas ABNT apresentado à comunidade de usuários \LaTeX.}
```

it basically states all the information from the cover, like the title, author and date. But I really need to place an image at the top center of the cover, but when I put the command "\begin{figure}" I'm not able to replace it on the center of the page

I have already tried using \centering, \begin{center} but none of these work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you make the example complete and compilable, so we can try things out? Possibly with a link to the template. Some guesses: remove `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` (so use only `\centering \includegraphics`), or put the `\includegraphics` in the element that appears on top, something like `\titulo{\includegraphics{FDUSP.jpg}\\Modela Canônico etc}`.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/project/5d1388f3af6c0d78691022da

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it would be better if you would post the code (shortened as much as you can while it still compiles) here in the question, to minimize the dependency on third party websites. Of course for the template itself that might not be possible, but at least provide the name and a link so it might be found later somewhere else if the original website doesn't work anymore for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [ab­n­tex2 package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/abntex2) includes this overleaf 677 line template I will just show that "unmodified" it works perfectly as expected such that simply including

```
\centering \includegraphics{filename}
```

works at the start of titlepage even when it is the older  2014 version.

[image]

That package has its own maintenance with latest 2018 release both in current TeX Live and MiKTeX (version 1.9.7 = 2018-11-24) with additional support at:-

https://github.com/abntex/abntex2

***However any problems you are having with the older overleaf version are best raised with overleaf.***